# String concatenated as an argument for a command

Tags: bash, shell

In bash shell, I would like to list file names under $folder (variable name in my code) with full path.

However, if I code like this,

```
dir $folder"*"
```

It outputs errors

```
"dir: cannot access <folder_name> : No such file or directory"
```

It works if I change the code like this,

```
search_str=$folder"*"
dir $search_str
```

It seems that the concatenated string to dir command is not what I intended and if I store the string in a variable and pass it only to dir command it works.

Anyone knows the reason & how not to use search_str?

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Note: I'm using standard Unix utility `ls` rather than [GNU-specific utility `dir`](https://askubuntu.com/a/615946/225111) (thanks, [hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl)) in the examples below, because the issue relates to generic shell behavior and is not limited to platforms with *GNU* utilities.</sup>

**tl;dr**

```
ls "$folder"* # double-quote the var. reference, use * unquoted
```

---

**Pattern (globbing) metacharacters such as `*` must be used *unquoted*** in order to be recognized as such.

Thus, `ls $folder"*"` will invariably *not* work as intended, because you (double-)*quoted* `*`.

By contrast, variable assignment `search_str=$folder"*"` causes the `*` to be appended to the value of `$folder` (as a *literal*, because it is double-quoted, but ultimately without quotes, because the shell removes the double quotes in the process of the string concatenation due to their having *syntactic* meaning rather than being *literals*; this removal is fittingly called *quote removal*).

It is **the *unquoted use* of the variable in command `ls $search_str` that then makes the `*` effective as a wildcard** (pattern metacharacter).

However, this **unquoted use of a variable is inherently *not robust***, because the value of `$search_str` is *as a whole* subject not only to globbing, but also to *word-splitting*, which means that the command would break if the original `$folder` variable contained a path with *embedded spaces*.

Therefore it is better to **append the `*` *on demand*, when globbing is actually needed:**

```
ls "$folder"*
```

Note how `*` is unquoted - to make it effective as a pattern metacharacter - whereas `"$folder"` is intentionally *double-quoted* - to ensure it is used *as-is* (word-splitting and globbing is not applied to its value).

Comment: Good answer! If you like, I found [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/615946/217021) an interesting read.

Comment: @hek2mgl: I appreciate the pointer - I had no idea `dir` even existed :) Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

suppose $folder is tmp then
dir $folder"*" is equivalent to `dir tmp*`

while in case of below

```
search_str=$folder"*"
dir $search_str
```

$search_str is equivalent to `dir temp`

when you use double quotes, it needs an extra step to expand. See more on Variable expansion in shell

Answer (score 0):

While @mklement0's answer explains the cause of the error, you may also look for possible other solutions. First let me borrow from the other answer the below line

> Pattern (globbing) metacharacters such as * must be used unquoted in
>   order to be recognized as such.

**Case 1:** If you wish to list(not parse, just list) the files(files only) recursively inside folder,
 use [[ globstar ]](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option#content-header).

```
shopt -s globstar
folder="yourfoldername**"
ls -p $folder | grep -v '/$'   #mind that '$folder' is not inside double quotes
# '-p' adds trailing slash to directories and we neglect those results using grep invert match
# Here I inadvertantly parsed the `ls` output, see the link in case 2 for why  you shouldn't do that.
```

**Case 2:** If you wish to parse(not just list) the files(files only) recursively inside a folder, use `find` as `ls` output cannot be parsed.<sup>[[Check this]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs#Why_you_shouldn.27t_parse_the_output_of_ls.281.29)</sup>

```
folder="yourfoldername" #no trailing **
find "$folder" -type f -print0 | while read -r -d '' fname
do
#do something with "$fname"
done
```

Comment: You are effectively parsing the output of `ls` with `grep`; any filename containing a newline will be seen by `grep` as two separate lines.

Comment: @chepner : Oops I inadvertently did.. I've added a note on this :)